# How to estimate the number of erroneous entries in a dataset?

Tags: measurement-error, collecting-data

Two researchers are tasked to independently collect a same set of data ($N$ observations) from a same set of subjects. For simplicity, let us assume they observe only one variable. After comparing their data, we notice a mismatch in $K$ observations. Obviously, *at least* $K$ values are wrong, though we don't know which researcher made a mistake. In the best possible case, one researcher made no mistake and the other one all $K$. But what if they both make mistakes with some individual probability, independently from each other? Then there could well be that they made the same mistake on a same subject and there would be no mismatch in their data, so these errors would pass unnoticed. (They could also make different mistakes on a same subject, so that neither of their values is correct. But, for the purpose of my question, I'd still count this as a single error (error in one subject)).

Is there a way to estimate the total number of errors in the data and what assumptions need to be made? Again, for simplicity, let us assume that the observed variable is categorical, so we don't need to worry about measurement errors.

How does the result generalise if we observe $M$ variables and have $K_1, K_2, \ldots, K_M$ mismatches? How if we have more than two researchers?

I guess this is a pretty standard problem in empirical research, but my quick search on CV didn't yield any results. My apologies if I missed an existing answer.

Comment: Just to check -- is your question equivalent to estimating the number of total errors, given that we've already observed $K$ mismatch errors? This seems to boil down to finding the number of expected *identical* mistakes (with sufficient independence assumptions), which is simply a binomial (or Poisson binomial) RV, and generalizes to arbitrary numbers of researchers or variables.